# Show hide links using angular js or JS on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

On click of "Show all" I want to show all elements, On click of link "1st half" , I want to show "abc" "def" and "ghi". ON click of 2nd link "2nd half", I want to show "jkl", "mno" and "pqr". Again on click of link "show all ", I want to show everything. "abc" , "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr".

There are some similar questions which I found and tried to implement that. But I am not able to display again the hidden element.

Here are the sample of code:

When I click "Show first half", in JS I am doing this:

```
document.getElementById("abc").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("def").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("ghi").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("jkl").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("mno").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("pqr").style.display = 'none';
```

Again when I click "Show All", I am doing this:

```
document.getElementById("abc").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("def").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("ghi").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("jkl").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("mno").style.display = 'visible';
document.getElementById("pqr").style.display = 'visible';
```

But this is not able to display the hidden element again.

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you comfortable using `ng-model` instend of using `document.getElementById("def").style.display` ? There are some directives specifically providerd by angularjs to show and hide elements.

Comment: My application is in angular only.. but I am new to this so.. May be I don't know . My problem is solved but if you can give me any link for this it will be very helpful for me. I will also try to learn more about such angular directive.

Comment: [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) and [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow). Should I write an example?

Comment: yup use ng-show with scope flag. That will make more sense if you are using angular.

Comment: @JK_Jha please check my answer below to achieve the same goal the angular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try avoiding use of elements for for task like these. You can achieve it by using ng-show or ng-if with the flags that you set in the scope variables.

First create the scope variables in the controller.

```
angular.module('sample', []);
angular.module('sample').controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.displayAll = true;
  $scope.displayOne = true;
  $scope.displayTwo = true;

  $scope.toggleDisplayAll = function(){
       $scope.displayAll = true;
       $scope.displayOne = $scope.displayAll;
       $scope.displayTwo = $scope.displayAll;
  };
  $scope.toggleDisplayOne = function(){
     $scope.displayOne = true;
     $scope.displayTwo = false;
  };
  $scope.toggleDisplayTwo = function(){
     $scope.displayTwo = true;
     $scope.displayOne = false;
  };

}]);
```

Now integrate those components into your html file.

```
    <body ng-app="sample">
     <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
       <button ng-click='toggleDisplayAll()'>Toggle All Display</button>
        <button ng-click='toggleDisplayOne()'>Toggle First Display</button>
        <button ng-click='toggleDisplayTwo()'>Toggle Second Display</button>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" ><strong>Go quickly to: </strong></a>
                                </div>


                                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <ul id="test1" class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li id="all_sep_branch" class="active"><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch('all_branch')">All branches </a></li>

                                        <li ng-show='displayOne'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">abc </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayOne'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">def </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayOne'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">ghi </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayOne'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">jkl </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayOne'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">mno </a></li>



                                        <li ng-show='displayTwo'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">pqr </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayTwo'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">stu </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayTwo'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">vwln </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayTwo'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">fsdfs </a></li>
                                        <li ng-show='displayTwo'><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()">fsddf</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>

 </div>  
  </body>
```

Also here is the [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vmp1i6It4RhnVcdfpIMG?p=preview)

**EDIT:** I have updated the plunker and answer to solve your css issue.

**EXPLAINATION ON WHY CSS WAS BREAKING:**
It was because you were using `<span>` tags between the `<li>` tags. That will break the parent child relation between the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. Also you were using the $scope.displayOne and $scope.displayTwo as functions when they are just scope variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this works like a magic.. but being a newebie to this.. may be again I am missing something..my css -styling is breaking after adding ng-show . Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using inline CSS or importing them from stylesheets? because scope variables have nothing to do with CSS except for the visibility of the elements it is applied to.

Comment: I am importing from stylesheets. `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul id="test1" class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li id="all_sep_branch" class="active"><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch('all_branch')">All branches </a></li>
         <span ng-show="displayOne">
          <li><a href="#" ng-click="load_data_for_branch()" </a></li>`  let me try to create plunker , if it helps

Comment: This is what my pluunkr with styling is before adding ng-show : https://plnkr.co/edit/t5aC12BktSP6kaqByJ87?p=preview  . After adding ng-show: https://plnkr.co/edit/6Z4azILWeWpbhsmxBbLC?p=preview

Comment: That is because you are using `<span>` tags in between the `<li>` tags. I will go ahead and update my answer and use your code on my plunker. give me 5 min.

Comment: I have updated the answer and the plunker also added description on why your css was failing. Make sure to change the accepted answer for doing it the angular way.

Comment: Thanks..it works as I want .since my app is in angular.. I will prefer your answer.. Thanks a lot @dishwasher ..

Answer (score 2):

[`CSS` display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) has no value `visible`. You should use `block` instead of `visible` to show hidden element like following.

```
document.getElementById("abc").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("def").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("ghi").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("jkl").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("mno").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("pqr").style.display = 'block';
```